How to display a heat map of range plots?
I am doing a bibliometric study and I am attempting to show the age ranges frequently studied in a particular field of research.
Each study typically picks an age range to pick their participants from, so I want to display the age groups researcher usually focus on the most. As its a bibliometric study, there might be so many age ranges to display, like over 50 ranges at minimum, which is much more than the regular range plots. So I was thinking of displaying these range plots overlaid over each other, where technically the range plots most frequently studied would look more opaque than others.
Is there any way to do this?

Could you show the current version you have? It will help to understand the situation quicker and accurately

I am not sure that it would be a very accurate way of displaying the information, but if that's what you want to do, then you could simply convert each age range into a single unit value that spans the range (so if the age range if from 1-10 then you would have values of 1 for 1-10), and then add them all together to give you the age height, then convert each height value into a particular colour.
However, heatmaps are much more powerful for showing the pattern across two dimensions, so single column heatmaps are not as effective as showing the actual dataset in full. There are actually examples of people asking how to do this in StackOverflow though.
